# how to not generate hash when uploading image files to ftp server with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image, ftp, upload

so I have successfully uploaded the image file to the ftp server and the image file is shaped like an auto generated hash file name, so how do I make the file name I upload is the same as the image name?, because when it is saved to the database it is not hashed but the name the file is the same as the uploaded image, but on the ftp server when saving it the file name is shaped like a hash

example upload file in ftp server :[image: []]

example controller :

```
$lampiran = Lampiran_tte::where('surat_tte_id', $surat->id);
                if ($request->hasfile('lampiran_gambar')) {
                  $files = [];
                    foreach ($request->file('lampiran_gambar') as $file) {
                      if ($file->isValid()) {
                          $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                          $file->store('/lampiranSurat', 'ftp') . '/' . $filename;
                          $files[] = [
                           'lampiran_gambar' => $filename,
                          ];
                      }
                   }
                   $gambar = '';
                   foreach ($files as $value) {
                   $gambar .= $value['lampiran_gambar'].'#';
                   }
                   $gambar = substr($gambar, 0, -1);
                   $lampiran->update([
                       'isi_lampiran'       => $request->isi_lampiran,
                       'lampiran_gambar'    => $gambar,
                       'update_by'          => Auth::user()->name,
                   ]);
                  }
```

if it is already stored in the database,
the image file name matches the image file name that was uploaded
example in database :[image: []]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `store()` function is generating the unique ID value for the file. Use the [`storeAs()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name) function instead which allows you to specify a filename of your choice.

```
$file->storeAs('/lampiranSurat', $filename, 'ftp');
```

Comment: if I use storeAs(), why does the image file name become ftp ?
example : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M6FMmRnQnEBAD3WIp704ffbc9H8EZlnW/view

example : $file->storeAs('/lampiranSurat', 'ftp') . '/' . $filename;

Comment: @gagaltotal666 Because as per the documentation I linked to shows, the second parameter for `storeAs()` is the name you want to assign the file. The first parameter is the file path. `storeAs()` is not used the same way.

Comment: @gagaltotal666 I have updated my answer to show how you might use `storeAs()`.

Comment: oh thanks you @Peppper... you save my live